# как в postgresql создать запрос отражающий все имеющиеся колонки в таблице и создать новую колонку с изменением типа данных с INTEGER на numeric?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Создана таблица, в ней есть колонки (id, ..., duration) необходимо отразить запросом все столбцы и добавить новый который из колонки duration посчитает нужное значение и округлит до десятых. У duration тип integer.
Пробую такой вариант, запрос нужный дает, а тип не удается изменить, помогите пожалуйста

```sql
UPDATE table
SET    duration = (duration/60), duration TYPE numeric(5,1) USING (duration::numeric(5,1))
WHERE film_duration>0
RETURNING *, duration AS duration_hours
```

Comment: Функция `CAST()`.

Comment: В выражение, которое *посчитает нужное значение и округлит до десятых*. Но не в показанном запросе - он вообще смахивает на бред, ибо изменить тип данных поля DML-запросом невозможно в принципе.